# Winning strategy with game of coins

Tags: combinatorics, induction, combinatorial-game-theory

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They
choose a natural number $n$ and build a stack of $n$ coins. Taking turns, they can remove 1,
2 or 3 coins from this stack. The player that takes the last coin loses the game. Alice gets to
play first. Suppose $n$ ≡ 1 mod 4. Prove that Bob always can win, independent of the moves Alice
makes.

My first thought was writing $n$ ≡ $1$ mod $4$ as $4 \mid n -1$. In other words, if $n$ is even and divisible by $4$, then Bob wins by taking 1 or 3 coins everytime. So, I think prove by induction should be used but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Working it out for small $n$ would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you. I tried for the basis $n = 1$, which gives $4 \mid 0$. For $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $n-1 = 4x$. Then, the I.S gives $4 \mid n+1-1 = (n-1)+1 = 4x+1$. But $4x+1$ is not divisible by 4. I guess this is totally wrong.

Comment: So an odd number of coins is remains?

Comment: As I said before, work it out for small $n$ to see what happens.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  And you got several of the smaller cases wrong.

Comment: Should say:  it is always assumed, in this sort of game, that both players move optimally.  With that assumption, the winner is always determined by the starting value.

Comment: It should be if 1 than Bob wins, 2 Bob lost, 3 Bob lost, 4 Bob lost, 5 Bob lost. For 6 coins, Bob only wins if Alice picks 3 or 2 coins.

Comment: Still have one of the small ones wrong, and your answer for $6$ does not make sense. Go carefully and slowly.  Don't guess at the answer.  Think through the moves.

Comment: This game (and its natural variants) is sometimes called "Poison".  You should be able to look it up online.

Comment: Ok thank you will continue tomorrow (CET). I mean 5 Bob wins.

Answer (score 1):

If Alice choses to remove $k$ coins for $k=1,2,3$, then Bob must remove $4-k$ coins. Therefore, when it is Alices turn to remove coins, the number of coins remaining will always be of the form $4m+1$. Therefore, after repeating this operation a certain amount of times, there will be only $1$ coin left on Alices turn, and so she will lose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the $4-k$ part. But the $4m+1$ is still not clear for me.

Comment: Well the number of coins you start with is of the form $4n+1$. Using this strategy, Alice and Bob remove $4$ coins between the $2$ of them and so when it is Alices $l$-th turn, there will be $4n+1-4(l-1)=4(n-l+1)+1$ coins remaining